# php cURL Imitating Ajax Calls

Tags: php, ajax, curl, cookies, libcurl

The web page I'm trying to retrieve data from is populating it's content with ajax calls to a specific page. The relevant call is like this:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: Data,
    url: '/example-ajax.aspx',
    timeout: _defaultTimeOut,
...
```

And this is the HTTP request (except the post data):

```
POST /example-ajax.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: *website*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: *http://website*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,      like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer:  *referrer*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: *very long cokie*
```

I can also get the relevant content with Postman tool with only setting post values along with referrer, origin and host headers.

What I do with libcurl is I first connect to login page with login info and save the cookie in cookiejar. Than I send a request to aforementioned ajax page but it returns json data with {Error: Unauthorized} paramater. There are no tokens or anything in local or web storages, only the cookie. So how can the server distinguish between a browser and a cURL request?

Here is my code to retrieve the cookie:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiejar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: example.com',
    'Origin: http://example.com'
    ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo)
```

And here is my request:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiejar);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host: example.com',
    'Origin: http://example.com',
    'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Content-Length:83',
    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    ));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after I've posted question, I've found out that simply sending a GET request instead of POST solves the problem. But for some reason both Postman and Browser are sending POST request to get the content, I thought I should do too with cURL. I was mistaken.